# I want to localize this newly created component in child publications using Tom.net API

Tags: tom.net

I have written a event handler that fires when a component is saved. I want newly created component to be localized in all the child publications. How can one find a lit of child publications. There is a property for finding parents publication but for child there is none.

Answer (score 5):

You can use

> BluePrintChainFilterData

Here's an example:

```
BluePrintChainFilterData filter = new BluePrintChainFilterData();
filter.Direction = BluePrintChainDirection.Down; var result =
ClientAdmin.GetListXml({THE_ID_OF_YOUR_ITEM}, filter);
```

This will return you XML containing all the data of your children elements.

There's different properties available on the BluePrintChainFilterData, if you're looking to filter down, sideways, shared items etc, these are all in the api docs.